# Google Apps Script - getDisplayValue() is not picking up calculated value

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get display value of a cell from a ss and displaying in another ss by doing follwing.

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ACTUAL_ID").getSheetByName("SheetName");
var value1 = SS.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue(); //values in A1 is calculated here
```

Putting values in array

```
var values = [[value1, value2]]; //multiple values from multiple spread sheets.
```

And printing them in another ss

```
targetSS.setActiveSelection("A2:H2").setValues(values);
```

But only some of the values are printed and for others, it prints #DIV/0! 
There is some value in original ss, it is not #DIV/0!.

All these values are calculated the same way in various ss and printed the same way, but some are printed and some are not!

Answer (score 1):

I dont see all of your code so I dont know how your getting the multiple values but here is a couple of simple ways to get all of the data on one sheet copied to another sheet.

```
function imTrying()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SSID');
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sht2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rng1=sht1.getDataRange();
  var valA=rng1.getValues(); 
  var rng2=sht2.getRange(1,1,valA.length,valA[0].length);
  rng2.setValues(valA);
}

function imTrying2()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SSID');
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sht2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rng1=sht1.getDataRange() 
  var rng2=sht2.getRange(1,1,rng1.getHeight(),rng1.getWidth());
  rng1.copyTo(rng2);
}
```

**Here's an image of the data I was copying:**

I guess I don't have enough reputation to embed images yet.  Oh well. It will work on any sort of data.